# Can a model trained on gpu used on cpu for inference and vice versa?

Tags: tensorflow

I was wondering if a model trained on the GPU could be use to run inference with the cpu ?
(And vice versa)
Thanks to you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it as long as your model doesn't have explicit device allocations. IE, if your model has blocks like `with tf.device('gpu:0')`, it'll complain when you run it on model without GPU.

In such cases you must make sure your imported model doesn't have explicit device assignments, for instance, but using `clear_devices` argument in [import_meta_graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#import_meta_graph)

Comment: Just to be sure, it means than with clear_devices=True I can use my model, even if I trained it with blocks like with tf.device('gpu:0'), on my CPU ?

Comment: yes, that clears devices and lets tf automatic placement algorithm use the available devices

Comment: it's also possible to save the model with cleared devices, to a SavedModel serialization:  see, for example `add_meta_graph()` in the  [SavedModelBuilder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/builder/SavedModelBuilder) class.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Can the `json` or `yaml` files themselves be manually rewritten to remove `with tf.device` statements?