# Tensorflow: Model trained(checkpoint files) on GPU can be converted to CPU running model?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, cpu, checkpoint

A model is trained with GPU and result is saved by checkpoint file. The saved checkpoint file can be run by cpu-tensorflow? If not, can convert the saved checkpoint file so as to run model in cpu-tensorflow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a model trained on gpu used on cpu for inference and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980035/can-a-model-trained-on-gpu-used-on-cpu-for-inference-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It normally can!

The exception is `with tf.device('gpu:0')` statements. If you do not have them in your code you are good to go!

Good luck!

Comment: If you do have device assignments in your code, you can remove them from the saved GraphDef .pb file with the remove_device rewriting rule: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/#remove_device