# set device on model trained on GPU and predict on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained a a model on a GPU and saved it like this (export_path is my output directory)

```
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

tensor_info_x = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(self.Xph)
tensor_info_y = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(self.predprob)
tensor_info_it = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(self.istraining)
tensor_info_do = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(self.dropout)

prediction_signature = (
       tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
              inputs={'myx': tensor_info_x, 'istraining': tensor_info_it, 'dropout': tensor_info_do},
              outputs={'ypred': tensor_info_y},
              method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
       net, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
       signature_def_map={
           tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
           prediction_signature },)
builder.save()
```

Now I'm trying to load this and run predictions. It works fine if I am on a GPU, but w/o a GPU around I get:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation 'rnn/while/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cell_0/layer_norm_basic_lstm_cell/dropout/add/Enter': Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
```

Now I read about tf.train.import_meta_graph and the clear_device option, but I can't get this work. I'm loading my models like so:

```
predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(modelname)
```

at which point is throw the error mentioned above. modelname is the full filename of the pb file. Is there a way to go through the nodes of the graph and manually set the device (or doing something similar)?
I'm using tensorflow 1.8.0

I saw [Can a model trained on gpu used on cpu for inference and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980035/can-a-model-trained-on-gpu-used-on-cpu-for-inference-and-vice-versa) which I don't think I'm duplicating.
The difference with that question is that I want to know what to do **after training**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up re-saving the models with 'clear_devices=True' on my GPU machine and then moving the saved models to my CPU-only machine. I couldn't find any concrete solution, so I post my script below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], m)
    loaded_graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    x = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('myx:0')
    dropout = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('mydropout:0')
    y = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('myy:0')
    export_path = 'somedirectory'
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path + '/mymodel')
    tensor_info_x = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(x)
    tensor_info_y = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(y)
    tensor_info_do = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(dropout)
    prediction_signature = (
                            tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
                            inputs={'myx': tensor_info_x, 'mydropout': tensor_info_do},
                            outputs={'myy': tensor_info_y}, 
                            method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                   signature_def_map={tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
                       prediction_signature }, clear_devices=True)
    builder.save()
```