# Is it possible to train model on GPU,then predict on CPU

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, cpu

I want to train my custom model with GPU devices.
I am wondering Will clients be able to use it via CPU ?

Comment: answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980035/can-a-model-trained-on-gpu-used-on-cpu-for-inference-and-vice-versa

Comment: I believe that after the model is trained it is just a set of ifs so - yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you do the heavy job of training on a GPU, save weights and then, your CPU will only do the matrix multiplication for predictions.

In `Tensorflow` and `Keras` you can train your model and save Neural Network weights:

Tensorflow:

```
# ON GPU
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/saved_model.ckpt")

# ON CPU
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/saved_model.ckpt")
```

Keras:

```
model.save_weights('your_model_weights.h5')
model.load_weights('your_model_weights.h5')
```

With `sklearn` algorithms, you can save weights this way:

```
model=XGBClassifier(max_depth=100, learning_rate=0.7, n_estimators=10, objective='binary:logistic',booster='gbtree',n_jobs=16,eval_metric="error",eval_set=eval_set, verbose=True)
clf=model.fit(x_train,y_train)
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, '/path/your_model.joblib')

model = joblib.load('/path/your_model.joblib')
model.predict(X_train)
```